# Do goblins have the ability to build printing presses or projectors?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

*We know that the Daily Prophet is a wizarding newspaper based in London. It is the primary source of news for British wizards.*

> How did they print newspapers?

Goblins are very capable metal smiths. They will do everything for wizards. We also know that Wizards must not use muggle artefacts; anything made by Muggles. So my question is:

> Did goblins build the printing machine?

In 1993, Severus Snape, filling in for Remus Lupin as a temporary Defence Against the Dark Arts professor, instructed Lupin's third year class to write an Essay on werewolves. He requested two rolls of parchment regarding the subject, concentrating on the ways of recognising and killing them.

> "You will each write an essay, to be handed in to me, on the ways you
>   recognise and kill werewolves. I want two rolls of parchment on the
>   subject, and I want them by Monday morning. It is time somebody took
>   this class in hand."

In that lesson Snape used projector to show pictures of werewolves.

> Who made that projector?

Comment: professor Snape only uses projector in the movie

Comment: @user13267: what about the Daily Prophet...news paper

Answer (score 3):

We do get a glimpse into how printing is done in the magical world, when we visit the Lovegoods and see the *Quibbler* being printed on a mechanical press:

> The thing that was making such a racket was a wooden object covered in magically turning cogs and wheels. It looked like the bizarre offspring of a workbench and a set of old shelves, but after a moment Harry deduced that it was an old-fashioned printing press, due to the fact that it was churning out *Quibblers*.

However, there’s probably a magical aspect involved: traditional presses don’t tend to include moving pictures. (Or am I getting the wrong papers?)

Work on the [Gutenberg press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press), which helped drive the mass production of books in Western Europe, was invented in the mid-fifteenth century. The International Statute of Secrecy didn’t come into effect until the late seventeenth, so the magical community would have been aware of the Muggle printing press. It’s quite plausible that they adopted it from the Muggles, and made their own “enhancements”. Or the process could be purely magical.

#### Goblins?

I do have to argue with two assertions in your question:

1. > They [goblins] will do everything for wizards.

   They really won’t. Goblin-wizard tensions have always been fairly terse. A lot of goblins believe ownership of the artefacts they make revert to the goblin family once the original owner dies, and not the family who bought the piece. Witness, for example, this conversation between Ron and Griphook in *Deathly Hallows*:

   > “The right to carry a wand,” said the goblin quietly, “has long been contested between wizards and goblins.”
   >
   > “Well, goblins can do magic without wands,” said Ron.
   >
   > “That is immaterial! Wizards refuse to share the secrets of wand- lore with other magical beings, they deny us the possibility of extending our powers!”

   Even if goblins invented the mechanical press (which seems unlikely – armour, weapons and treasure seems more up their street), I doubt they’d have shared it willingly with humans.
2. > We also know that Wizards must not use Muggle artefacts; anything made by Muggles.

   Nope.

   While certain families may despise Muggle artefacts, and the workarounds Muggles use because they don’t have magic, I don’t think there’s evidence for a *blanket ban* on Muggle-designed artefacts in the magical community. They might prefer a magical solution, but they won’t eschew the Muggle solution if it’s all they have.

   I think this also answers the question of the slide projector: Muggle invention, adopted by the magical community.

Comment: I'd like to present the Weasley's Flying Car as solid proof that some wizards are perfectly happy using muggle technology...though I think they did get into a bit of trouble for it being seen by some Muggles.

Comment: Perhaps the OP mistook electrical items for all muggle items: Electrical items do not work in areas of high magic (such as Hogwarts)

Comment: @Zibbobz: It is illegal to use flying car as regarding to Wizards..